# TypeError: community.on is not a function

Tags: node.js

My node -v is 8.7 (the newest)
Here is the code lines:

```
community.on('confKeyNeeded', function(tag, callback) {
    callback(null, time, SteamTotp.getConfirmationKey(account.identity_secret, time(), tag));
});

community.on('newConfirmation', function(confirmation) {
    var time = time();
    var key = SteamTotp.getConfirmationKey(account.identity_secret, time, 'allow');
    confirmation.respond(time, key, true, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            logger.error('Error on mobile auth');
            logger.debug(err);
            return;
        }
        logger.trace('Trade sucesfully confirmed');
    });
});
```

And im getting here this error:

```
  root@kokojambo13371:/var/bot# node bot_manager.js
        Database connection ID: 53
        List of bots:
        Launching bot# 1
        Bot with ID 1 started
        /var/bot/bot.js:228
        community.on('confKeyNeeded', function(tag, callback) {
                  ^

    TypeError: community.on is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/bot/bot.js:228:11)
        at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
    Bot stopped with code 1
    /var/bot/bot.js:228
    community.on('confKeyNeeded', function(tag, callback) {
              ^

    TypeError: community.on is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/bot/bot.js:228:11)
        at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
    Bot stopped with code 1`enter code here`
    ^Z
    [1]+  Stopped                 node bot_manager.js
```

Using hosting firstvds, ubuntu 14.04, 512mb

Comment: Please post the complete code, or the part where you have declared the `community` variable

Comment: Please don't post clutter or try to pay for help here. Neither of those is appropriate. And if the system is telling you something is wrong with your post, *something is wrong with your post*. That's not an invitation to add a bunch of junk.

Answer (score 0):

```
community.on('newConfirmation', function(confirmation) {
    var time = time();
    var key = SteamTotp.getConfirmationKey(account.identity_secret, time, 'allow');
    confirmation.respond(time, key, true, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            logger.error('Error on mobile auth');
            logger.debug(err);
            return;
        }
        logger.trace('Trade sucesfully confirmed');
    });
});

function query(sql, callback) {
    if (typeof callback === 'undefined') {
        callback = function() {};
    }
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        logger.info('DB connection ID: '+connection.threadId);
        connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
            if(err) return callback(err);
            connection.release();
            return callback(null, rows);
        });
    });
}``
```

Comment: Is this intended to be an answer? If so, some explanation would be helpful. It looks like you should have added it to your post using the "edit" link beneath the question. Please only post answers that solve the problem.